# Div background-color not inherited in bootstrap form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div that surrounds a bootstrap form.
When I define a background-color to that div the background-color is not seen in the form.

**ADD**: I added the three major divs before the wrapper_form - div so that you get the full picture. Before the first major div there starts the body tag.

This is my code:

```css
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
.main-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 50px 0 0px 0;
}
.content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 36px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0 15px;
    overflow:auto;
}

.wrapper_form {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="main-wrapper">
        <div class="content">

<div class="wrapper_form">
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label class="control-label">Input:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="myInput" id="myInput" value="" />                  
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div><!-- /.content-->
</div><!-- /.main-wrapper -->
</div><!-- /.wrapper -->
```

Comment: its working fine jsfiddle for me.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hrk0hr41/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inside elements are floated - try toggling the float property on the columns and you'll see the styling takes.

If you float the wrapper element it'll take the yellow background.

Answer (score 1):

```
.wrapper_form {background-color: yellow !important;}
```

Comment: You should add a description to your answer instead of just posting one line of code so that the OP learns *why* you are recommending this, otherwise it tends to lead to people just copying and pasting code without understanding what it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
.form-group:after,.form-group:before{
 clear:both;
 content:'';
 display:table;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

```
.wrapper_form {
  background-color: yellow !important;
 }
```

Try this

Comment: Thx, but does not affect anything.